# Jquery visitor counter regularly checking MySQL table

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, counter

There used to be a counter on the front page of clickbank which said how much money affiliates had made so far. Nothing unusual except this one slowly clicked up the dollars right in front of your eyes.

I'm looking for something similar but for a visitor counter. I'm OK with the php and MySQL to hold the data but I would like a counter that updates by, for example, checking the database every 10 seconds and adjusting the count.

My gut feeling says jquery holds the answer but that is where I run dry and can't find anything on the net beyond the normal counters which only refresh when you reload the page.

Is it possible?

Many thanks for any ideas or pointers.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Usually that's not a very good question to ask when it comes to programming, most things are possible in one way or another. In your case, you can use either setInterval or setTimeout to repeatedly send an ajax request to get the data and update your page.

Comment: Thanks, Not being a hyper jquery wizard - do you know any online tutorials for it. I've found ones that do ajax requests for form filling but not this ... ?

Comment: Another thing to consider is that sometime counters like that "cheat" a little, by estimating the rate of change, and only polling occasionally or on refresh.  It saves on network accesses, but accomplishes the same thing for the most part.  It just depends on whether you care about being absolutely correct, or conveying what is generally occurring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with something like this.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var updateInterval = 10000; // 10 seconds, in milliseconds

        function updateCounter(){

            $.ajax({
            url: 'ajaxCall/path...',
            dataType: "json",
            type: "GET",
            success: function(returnValue){
                    $('selector').text(returnValue);
                }
        });
        }

      setInterval(updateCounter, updateInterval);
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Don't know why this has been marked as not a real question - your script looks like it has all the right ingredients, I'll give it a try. Thanks

Comment: Right, I got it working with this:      $("#responsecontainer").load("response.php");
   var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
      $("#responsecontainer").load('response.php');
   }, 9000);
   $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
where response.php just generates the visitor number from the database